# Should the pgrep command be available in OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, terminal

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32154463/2871638) on stackexchange and was told in no uncertain terms that my system was broken because pgrep did not exist in `/usr/bin`

This has me worried, my system is stable and I am sure I did not 'accidentally' delete pgrep from the `/usr/bin` directory.

I checked one of my other (newer systems) and indeed pgrep is available.

Is pgrep shipped by Apple in 10.7.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not shipped until 10.8 so you'll need to get it elsewhere for 10.7 and earlier.

Starting with OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, the `pgrep` command should be in `/usr/bin/`.

In a Terminal type the following and press enter.

```
whereis pgrep
```

Looking at the contents of the InstallESD.dmg from "Install Mac OS X Lion.app", `pgrep` is not present.

Comment: that was the first command I used to check. ;-)

Comment: Chanks! Much appreciated, laziness on part, I have the Install dmg for Lion as well, could have checked myself.

Comment: Had I known that I wouldn't have gotten out of bed to go check. :)

Answer (score 5):

`pgrep` is a fairly new addition to OS X. It may not be available in 10.7 I would use pkgutil and check for a package id and install time or the command is not available in your version OS X.

```
pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/pgrep
```

Comment: I am looking for some documentation, which would confirm if it should or should not be there.